# Can't add sub pages in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using RoR 2.3.8

This is my `cities_controller.rb`

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @city = City.find(params[:id])
    ...
  end

  def shops
    ...
  end

  def countries
    ...
  end
end
```

Here's my `routes.rb`

```
map.resources :cities, :collection => {:shops => :get, :countries => :get}
```

The `show` url for each `id` is:

```
http://localhost/cities/1
```

I want to have some contents `shops` and `countries` for each associated `id`, which I want:

```
http://localhost/cities/1/shops
http://localhost/cities/1/countries
```

I can't get the pages showed in empty code in the first place. What have I done wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The `:collection` option is for when you want to act on the whole collection - so your routes will show up as:

```
http://localhost/cities/shops
http://localhost/cities/countries
```

What you want is

```
map.resources :cities, :member => {:shops => :get, :countries => :get}
```

Reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Resources/resources

Answer (score 0):

Shops and Countries would probably not be methods in the controller but other models. you would want a `Countries.rb` and `Shops.rb`

You would then nest the resources like

```
resources :cities do
     resources :shops
end
```

and you would need a `belongs_to :city` in the shops model and a `has_many :shops` in the cities model which would let you access cities/1/shops.... or something like that

However think about the way the data is structured, do countries really belong to cities (which nesting the resources would imply) or would countries contain cities. You would want cities `belongs_to :country` and so on...

This help?

Comment: Yes, I do search some stuff with the controller and show the result in the view, but there on the model side, there is no association. The data structure is just an example. :P